# CSOM vs JSOM vs SSOM vs REST

Tags: 2010, 2013, community

There does not seem to be any clear explanation of the different hosting types and technology abbreviations, so I decided to make a community post about the different types.
Perhaps there will never be any good distinctions, but we here at SharePoint Stack Exchange can at least coin our own definitions and perhaps live by these. I believe this could make everything much easier. I hope others will edit this post so it becomes even more correct, as there are probably a lot of errors and subjective ignorance.

Comment: Great initiative Eirik!

Comment: Any thoughts on whether it would be appropriate to incorporate remote applications (e.g. desktop/winforms) which sync or present data in SharePoint? They can't reliably use SSOM if they are indeed remote, but they could definitely use CSOM if they're in .Net or can implement the assemblies (Powershell, perhaps) -- these possibilities don't seem to be well represented here, possibly because they're not incredibly popular(?)

Answer (score 94):

#**2013**

Model Types:

- **CSOM**: Client-side object model. **C#** (or **Visual Basic**) *only*, use [NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SharePoint.Client/), at the moment same package for both 2010 and 2013.
- **JSOM**: JavaScript object model. **JavaScript** *only*.

  - `SP.ClientContext.get_current()` for normal use. `new SP.ClientContext('url...')` for specific `SPSite`. Note this works cross-**SPSite** in 2013.
- **SSOM**: Server-side object model. **C#** (or **Visual Basic**) *only*, use `Microsoft.SharePoint` (15) DLL. Must be deployed on same farm.
- **REST**: REST web technologies and standard Open Data Protocol (OData) syntax.
- Either JS (JavaScript) or **C#** (or **Visual Basic**) [helper package in NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/packages/d4s.sp2013.rest/).

Hosting:

- **SharePoint hosted**: **JavaScript** and templates only. By templates I mean list templates, content types, etc. Anything that can be uploaded to the SharePoint virtual file system can also be added, such as  *.aspx*-pages.
- **Autohosted**: **C#** (or **Visual Basic**) only. Currently only supported on Office 365. On app purchase an Azure instance will be automatically provisioned. Uses OAuth to comunicate to SharePoint site.
- **Provider hosted**: **C#** (or **Visual Basic**). Similar to **Autohosted**, but is meant to be hosted more manually (i.e. On Azure). So you fire up a web application, on any server, and then use **S2S** to connect to SharePoint.
- **Sandboxed**: Remnant from 2010, can be uploaded to Solution gallery. Support for limited subset of the SSOM. No file access, so can not deploy anything to _**layouts** folder. If you use the limited SSOM-part (C#) your solution will be considered deprecated. Support for templates such as list templates and content types, deployed directly to host web.
- **Farm solution**: Full access, deploy through PowerShell.

Technologies table:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------+
¦               ¦ CSOM ¦ JSOM ¦ SSOM ¦ REST JS ¦ REST C# ¦
¦---------------+------+------+------+---------+---------¦
¦ JavaScript    ¦      ¦  x   ¦      ¦  x      ¦         ¦  
¦ C#            ¦  x   ¦      ¦  x   ¦         ¦  x      ¦  
¦ From browser  ¦      ¦  x   ¦      ¦  x      ¦         ¦  
¦ From server   ¦  x   ¦      ¦  x   ¦         ¦  x      ¦  
¦ OAuth2        ¦  x   ¦  x   ¦  x   ¦  x      ¦  x      ¦  
¦ S2S           ¦  x   ¦      ¦  x   ¦         ¦         ¦ 
+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

Hosting table:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
¦                     ¦ CSOM ¦ JSOM ¦ SSOM        ¦ REST JS ¦ REST C# ¦
¦---------------------+------+------+-------------+---------+---------¦
¦ SharePoint hosted   ¦      ¦  x   ¦             ¦         ¦         ¦
¦ Autohosted          ¦  x   ¦      ¦             ¦         ¦  x      ¦ 
¦ Provider hosted     ¦  x   ¦      ¦             ¦         ¦         ¦ 
¦ Sandboxed solution  ¦  x   ¦  x   ¦  x(limited) ¦  x      ¦  x      ¦
¦ Farm solution       ¦  x   ¦  x   ¦  x          ¦  x      ¦  x      ¦ 
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

#**2010**

Model Types:

- **CSOM**: Client-side object model. **C#** (or **Visual Basic**) [NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SharePoint.Client/)
- **JSOM**: JavaScript object model. **JavaScript** *only*.

  - `SP.ClientContext.get_current()` for normal use. `new SP.ClientContext('url...')` for specific `SPWeb`. Note that you are  only able to access content within the current site collection in SharePoint 2010.
- **SSOM**: Server-side object model. **C#** (or **Visual Basic**) *only*, use `Microsoft.SharePoint` (14) DLL. Must be deployed on same farm.
- **REST**: REST in 2010 is only for `ListData.svc`. Note that [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/) (jQuery plugin) utilizes the **.asmx** services in _/*vti/bin* , such as _*/*vti_bin/Webs.asmx**

Technologies table:

```
+--------------------------------------------+
¦               ¦ CSOM ¦ JSOM ¦ SSOM ¦ REST  ¦
¦---------------+------+------+------+-------¦
¦ JavaScript    ¦  x   ¦  x   ¦      ¦  x    ¦  
¦ C#            ¦  x   ¦      ¦  x   ¦  x    ¦  
¦ From browser  ¦      ¦  x   ¦  x   ¦  x    ¦  
¦ From server   ¦  x   ¦      ¦  x   ¦       ¦  
+--------------------------------------------+
```

Hosting table:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
¦                     ¦ CSOM ¦ JSOM ¦ SSOM        ¦ REST JS ¦ REST C# ¦
¦---------------------+------+------+-------------+---------+---------¦
¦ Sandboxed solution  ¦  x   ¦  x   ¦  x(limited) ¦  x      ¦  x      ¦
¦ Farm solution       ¦  x   ¦  x   ¦  x          ¦  x      ¦  x      ¦ 
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: SPSite site = new SPSite(); this is classified under  ?

Comment: Hi @Nikhil, what do you mean? Perhaps we could start a chat, I imagine a lot of questions/suggestions/changes might need some discussion.

Comment: how do we chat on stackexchange ? :-)

Comment: Something like this: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13812/csom-vs-jsom-vs-ssom-vs-rest

Comment: CSOM, JSOM and rest end points are not secure for public facing web site with anonymous access, usually administrator block access to "_vti_bin" folder and all these modal types use web service and are located in that folder.

Comment: I know I am a bit late to the party, but could you clarify what you mean by "Hosting"? I'm not sure I understand what is going on there ;).