# new features/capabilities in sharepoint 2013 CSOM as compared to sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server

Can someone please tell me about all the new features/capabilities in sharepoint 2013 CSOM as compared to sharepoint 2010.

I cannot find any useful link about the same in google

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/93269/csom-vs-jsom-vs-ssom-vs-rest) is pretty comphrensive. Rest is a big deal in 2013, and the App model, a new addition to the SP2013 stack, works entirely on CSOM