# intranet/extranet responsive sharepoint 2013 - best practice and tips

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, responsive

I have a SP 2010 that would like to migrate to SP 2013 but I'm still not sure if I would need to migrate or just start fresh.

I would like SP 2013 enterprise to be a responsive site using both forms of authentication windows and forms an also used has an extranet.

I'm happy to purchase a theme if its going to reduce the amount of work done.
Any resources links or tips would be appreciated

Comment: Also see http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/164419/responsive-framework-for-sharepoint-online-2013

Answer (score 0):

Check out this guy, seems very nice job, there are two free templates too:
http://www.topsharepoint.com/somnio-premium-sharepoint-2013-theme