# How to create a custom responsive master page by using some other frameworks like bootstrap,etc?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, responsive-template

what are the possible ways to create a custom responsive master page by using frameworks like bootstrap,etc.I am not sure about Device channel in 2013?

Answer (score 0):

I am in the process of building one at the moment, here are the steps I  have followed roughly.

1- I have created a basic html master page in design manager

2- I referenced JQuery, BootStraps etc. in this

3- Using Snippets, I have started building the components I want to see on my master page, I am going by adding BootStrap classes on top of already there.

4- Created my own CSS file, linked this using the Alternate CSS settings on Master Page settings page.

5- Created a page layout to go with it.

All done using SP Designer & SharePoint interface. Hope this helps. Haven't used the Device Channel yet, but I think it's basically changing the master page/styling for different devices..

Answer (score 0):

as ova noted you can develop it yourself or download a codeplex project that someone has done it for you. They use bootstrap and zurb. its for 2013 and for 2010.

https://responsivesharepoint.codeplex.com/

or a bit more work:

http://www.topsharepoint.com/shareboot-responsive-sharepoint-2013-theme

doing it yourself is a grate way of learning but is complex if your not familiar and takes a long time to make sure you dont lose needed functionality when amending the masterpage.

there is already a discussion on this topic on stackexchange and so far bootstrap to my understanding is one of the best ones out in the market, even google is using it in chrome.

[Responsive framework for SharePoint Online 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/164419/responsive-framework-for-sharepoint-online-2013)

as for device channels that is dependent on requirements. both do same functionality but device channels are mainly used for mobile devices and to target specific functionalities that will give it a different look. So on a mobile device you want them to display small icons and small banners that when clicked opens an app or install their mobile app from the website when clicked on a mobile device using the browser but you want to display normal icons and normal banners or no banners on the desktop version.

device channels have a smaller foot trail as you can have multiple css, layouts and masterpages that only load depending on the device.