# Sharepoint CSOM Mapper

Tags: csom, .net, mvc, mapping-engine

Hi I'm new to SharePoint and developing with it, but having done a few tutorials I'm trying to get myself off on the right foot and put together a solution.

Firstly the solution has already been made in SharePoint 2010, but I think that it can be done better by using a client based system and in a MVC architecture. So basically putting a much friendlier face on the current solution.

I went through a solution using ClientContext and setting my sharepoint url and then got to Caml - so I did a bit of that and then used https://camlex.codeplex.com/ to make the Caml queries easier.

I was stil left though with a feeling that something that did the mapping to a 'normal' object (like entityFramework) was missing.

So I've been trying to use http://sharepointcommon.codeplex.com/ but everytime I try down this route I get messages to install Microsoft.* sharepoint libraries. Which I install and install and mark as copy to local directory but it never seems to actually work.

I've tried others as well (Kraken) but I'm equally stumped.

The lack of an example which seems to apply to me seems to be missing.

So could anyone give me
a) An example of using ClientContext in SharepointCommon
b) Another Mapping tool that is working for them.

I'm using .net4.5.2

Comment: Ended up using 
https://sennitspmapper.codeplex.com/
The documentation isn't very good but it's good enough and small enough to play around with to add some more functionality without it being a massive difficulty