# What is client object model SharePoint 2013?

Tags: development, rest, visual-studio, csom

I am new to SharePoint, I want to know what is CSOM and REST in SharePoint 2013.
what is the basic difference between CSOM and REST in SharePoint 2013

Comment: Related: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/93269/csom-vs-jsom-vs-ssom-vs-rest

Answer (score 2):

Very simple

Both are used to access the SP data.

**CSOM**

Access the SP data from the client side. Code will executed in the client side not in SP server.

CSOM include .Net, Java Script, jQuery, Silverlight. It required reference should included in code development,

For example **Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll** and **Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll**

For more information : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179912.aspx

**REST**

Access the SP data via HTTP URL. Result will be XML or JSON.

It not required any reference and platform independent.

For more inofrmation : 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142380.aspx