# Check the logged in user is a farm admin or not using jquery

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise

How to check the logged in user is a farm admin or not using jQuery in SharePoint 2010?

Comment: You can check whether the user is a site collection administrator or not only using JSOM. There is no way to check  farm admin or not as far as I know

Answer (score 6):

SharePoint 2010 Farm solution objects are **not allowed** to use in JSOM.

Check the hosting table for SharePoint 2010 in below given link.

[CSOM vs JSOM vs SSOM vs REST](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/93269/csom-vs-jsom-vs-ssom-vs-rest)