# CSOM and JSOM functionnalities

Tags: csom, jsom

Which API between CSOM and JSOM propose most possibilities of customization ? (I mean, can I do the exactly the same things with this API's)

Comment: Which kind of customization you are talking about? Be more specific !!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your answer you should know what is [JSOM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh372944%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), and what is [CSOM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ff798388.aspx).

If you know the difference between these two then you can easily decide what you should [choose](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/general-development/choose-the-right-api-set-in-sharepoint).

If you need to learn more about difference between JSOM and CSOM, here are certain helpful resources.

- [CSOM vs JSOM](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sagarp/csom-vs-jsom-vs-ssom-vs-rest/)
- [CSOM vs JSOM vs SSOM vs REST](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/93269/csom-vs-jsom-vs-ssom-vs-rest)