# Is it possible to use SSOM for Sharepoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, ssom

I know, to use SSOM it must be deployed on same farm. Is there any way to use SSOM to work with Sharepoint Online?
Thank you.

Comment: Not Possible. pls go through https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/93269/csom-vs-jsom-vs-ssom-vs-rest

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The clear answer is

> No, You cannot use Server Object Model in SharePoint Online.

So what may be an alternative?

- If you have some sort of SSOM codes then you can convert that codes to CSOM(Managed CSOM, JavaScript or REST API) whatever is more convenient to you.
- Also, SharePoint Online does not entertain any deployment of managed CSOM, you can code your requirement to SharePoint Provider Hosted Add-in.
- Also you can code your requirement as WCF services and consume it using JavaScript.